# Drop Animation Function for connect four game in JS and SVG

Tags: javascript, css, function, svg

I'm new to programming and currently trying my hand at a project. My code is certainly not good, however, I would like to have a function for my game, with which I can throw a chip in each column, in which I click on the top of the respective button. Is my approach completely wrong or is it possible to work with the current state? Would be glad about tips

```css
body {
  background-color: #cecece;
}

h1 {
  background-color: rgb(205, 169, 247);
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

h3 {
  background-color: #fabd68;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 400px;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #e26262;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

p {
  background-color: #85e4a1;
  border: 3px dotted black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 900px;
  margin-top: -210px;
}

h4 {
  background-color: rgb(148, 203, 240);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 900px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.A {
  offset-path: path('M 80 -10 l 0 70 l 0 75 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70');
  offset-distance: 0%;
  animation: red-ball 1s linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes red-ball {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  to {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}

.A:hover {
  fill: #68fa88;
}

.B:hover {
  fill: #68fa88;
}

.C:hover {
  fill: #68fa88;
}

.D:hover {
  fill: #68fa88;
}

.E:hover {
  fill: #68fa88;
}

.F:hover {
  fill: #68fa88;
}

.G:hover {
  fill: #68fa88;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title>My first webpage</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
  <script src='main.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="550" height="500">
    <path class="line1" d="M 45 35 l 0 70 l 0 75 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
    <path class="line2" d="M 115 35 l 0 70 l 0 75 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
    <path class="line3" d="M 185 35 l 0 70 l 0 75 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
    <path class="line4" d="M 255 35 l 0 70 l 0 75 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
    <path class="line5" d="M 325 35 l 0 70 l 0 75 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
    <path class="line6" d="M 395 35 l 0 70 l 0 75 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
    <path class="line7" d="M 465 35 l 0 70 l 0 75 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70 l 0 70" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />

    <circle class="A"cx="45" cy="35" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>
    <circle class="B"cx="115" cy="35" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68" />
    <circle class="C"cx="185" cy="35" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68" />
    <circle class="D"cx="255" cy="35" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68" />
    <circle class="E"cx="325" cy="35" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68" />
    <circle class="F"cx="395" cy="35" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68" />
    <circle class="G"cx="465" cy="35" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68" />
            
    <rect class="col1 row1" x="10" y="70" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos1/1"cx="45" cy="105" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col2 row1" x="80" y="70" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos2/1"cx="115" cy="105" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col3 row1" x="150" y="70" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos3/1"cx="185" cy="105" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col4 row1" x="220" y="70" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos4/1"cx="255" cy="105" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col5 row1" x="290" y="70" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos5/1"cx="325" cy="105" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col6 row1" x="360" y="70" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos6/1"cx="395" cy="105" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col7 row1" x="430" y="70" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos7/1"cx="465" cy="105" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col1 row2" x="10" y="140" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos1/2"cx="45" cy="175" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col2 row2" x="80" y="140" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos2/2"cx="115" cy="175" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col3 row2" x="150" y="140" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos3/2"cx="185" cy="175" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col4 row2" x="220" y="140" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos4/2"cx="255" cy="175" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col5 row2" x="290" y="140" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos5/2"cx="325" cy="175" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col6 row2" x="360" y="140" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos6/2"cx="395" cy="175" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col7 row2" x="430" y="140" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <circle style="visibility:hidden" class="Pos7/2"cx="465" cy="175" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#fabd68"/>

    <rect class="col1 row3" x="10" y="210" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect  class="col2 row3" x="80" y="210" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect  class="col3 row3" x="150" y="210" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect  class="col4 row3" x="220" y="210" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect  class="col5 row3" x="290" y="210" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect  class="col6 row3" x="360" y="210" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect  class="col7 row3" x="430" y="210" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col1 row4" x="10" y="280" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col2 row4" x="80" y="280" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col3 row4" x="150" y="280" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col4 row4" x="220" y="280" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col5 row4" x="290" y="280" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col6 row4" x="360" y="280" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col7 row4" x="430" y="280" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />

    <rect class="col1 row5" x="10" y="350" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col2 row5" x="80" y="350" width="70" height="70"70
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col3 row5" x="150" y="350" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col4 row5" x="220" y="350" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col5 row5" x="290" y="350" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col6 row5" x="360" y="350" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col7 row5" x="430" y="350" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col1 row6" x="10" y="420" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col2 row6" x="80" y="420" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col3 row6" x="150" y="420" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col4 row6" x="220" y="420" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col5 row6" x="290" y="420" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col6 row6" x="360" y="420" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
    <rect class="col7 row6" x="430" y="420" width="70" height="70"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1" />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

It's the first time I use StackOverflow, I hope it's right.
I've tried to create a path and run the animation and for the first 2 rows I have invisible circles where I thought that these should then become visible so that a circle remains inside. After several hours I am just completely stumped.

Comment: What's inside your `main.js` file? Can you post that here? If not (too much code), can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: My main.js is completely empty, thats my problem.

Comment: my current structure is only about HTML and CSS and an animation that runs down the first column

Comment: Your question shouldn't be "How do I program this game"; but "How do I run an animation, where the circle is positioned at the end of an animation" In general; Don't try to create the whole game at once. Break up functionality and program/learn in pieces.

Comment: add a 'forwards' end state to: ``animation: red-ball 1s linear forwards``